# PHP + RSS duplicate elements

Tags: php

Im using this PHP to get a list of Title's from an RSS feed:

```
<?php require_once('magpie/rss_fetch.inc');
$rss = fetch_rss('http://live.visitmix.com/Sessions/RSS');

foreach ($rss->items as $item) { 
    $cat = $item['category'];
    $title = $item['title'];
        echo '<li class="'.$cat.'">'.$title.'</li>';
}

?>
```

I want to use `<category>` and add it as the class, however the `<category>` element appears for each `<item>` 1,2,3,4 or more times depending on the Title. How can I take the category element and seperate each category with a space if there is more than 1?

Comment: What is the content of $cat when there is more than 1 category?

Comment: A string containing all <category> strings

Comment: E.g. OneTwoThree if 
<category>One</category>
<category>Two</category>
<category>Three</category>

Comment: OK so you want 'OneTwoThree' to becomes 'One Two Three'? I guess OneTwoThree can be ApplesOrangesBananas? The separator is a capital letter?? Can a "token" contain multiples capitals like 'MyNamesPaulJulia' who would become 'MyNames Paul Julia'?

Comment: Ahh yes, seperate by capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about accumulating the categories in an array and then implode the array?

```
$categoriesArray = array();

foreach ($rss->items as $item) { 
    array_push($categoriesArray, $item['category']);
}
$categories = implode(" ", $categoriesArray);
```

**EDIT TO ADD**

If the categories are cumulated, you can try something like this:

```
$categoriesByTitle = array();

foreach ($rss->items as $item) { 
        $currentTitle = $item['title'];
        $categories = $categoriesByTitle[$currentTitle];
        if ($categories == NULL) {
            $categories = array();
            $categoriesByTitle[$currentTitle] = $categories;
        }
        if (!in_array($item['category'], $categories)) {
            array_push($categories, $item['category']);
        }
}
foreach ($categoriesByTitle as $title=>$category) {
    // use implode for each title
    $categoryString = implode(" ", $category);
    echo '<li class="'.$categoryString.'">'.$title.'</li>';
}
```

Check this [reference for arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ref_array.asp), it could be very useful for dealing with this kind of problems

Comment: But how can i apply the categories to the correct list item. 

This gives me an array of all categories.

Comment: can you post a sample of the XML you are dealing with?